# Fourth derivative

Tags: calculus

Find the fourth derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ if
$$f (2x^2-1) = 2x×f (x)$$

I substituted $x= \cos t$ and then kind of back substituted again to get $f(x)$  approximately equal to $0$ but that doesn't answer the question

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What do you mean be "kind of back substituted"?

Comment: Why would you substitute $x=\cos t$?  Is there more context here?

Comment: to state the obvious:  $f(x)\equiv 0$ is a solution to this functional equation so the answer, if it is the same for all solutions, has to be $0$.

Comment: I wrote cost in terms of cos(t/2^n)

Answer (score 1):

The given equation means $x\,f(x)=-x\,f(-x)$, i.e. $f(x)$ must be an odd function. So if $f(x)$ has a fourth derivative at $x=0$, it must be zero. Whether a non-trivial solution regular at $x=0$ exists, is another question, I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your relation, we can take the derivatives order by order:

$$f'(2x^2 - 1) = 2f(x) + 2xf'(x)$$

$$f''(2x^2 - 1) = 2f'(x) + 2f'(x) + 2xf''(x)$$

$$f'''(2x^2 - 1) = 2f''(x) + 2f''(x) + 2f''(x) + 2xf'''(x)$$

$$f''''(2x^2 - 1) = 2f'''(x) + 2f'''(x) + 2f'''(x) + 2f'''(x) + 2xf''''(x)$$

So that

$$f''''(2x^2 - 1) = 8f'''(x) + 2xf''''(x)$$

But to find $f''''(0)$ we need the fifth derivative, since here $f''''(x)$ doesn't appear.

Hence

$$f^{(5)}(2x^2 - 1) = 8 f^{(4)}(x) + 2f^{(4)}(x) + 2xf^{(5)}(x)$$

And at $x = 0$ we get

$$f^{(5)}(-1) = 8f^{(4)}(0) + 2f^{(4)}(0)$$

Eventually

$$f^{(4)}(0) = \frac{1}{8}f^{(5)}(-1)$$